# Change Color of Active Tab in Oracle APEX Tabs Container

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created Tabs Container in Oracle APEX
[image: Tabs Coantainer]

I wish to know how to change the color of the active tab to inform user which tab is currently selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest method is to open Theme Roller and in Custom CSS tab enter the fallowing:

```
.t-Header .a-MenuBar-item.a-Menu--current, .t-Header .a-MenuBar-item.a-Menu--current.is-focused {
    background-color: #cacaca;
}
```

Alternatively you can add this CSS on a Page 0 or add it in the theme template or write it in a css file that you upload as a Static Application File and reference the file in page template.